# Importance of features in Dataset using Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

How we can calculate the importance of features in data set using machine learning ? which algorithm will be better and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods that fit a model to the data and based on the fit classify the features from most relevant to less relevant. If you want to know more just google feature selection.

I don't know which language you're using but here's a link to a python page about it: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

You can use this function:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE

This will eliminate the less meaningful features from you dataset based on a fit from a classifier, you can choose for instance logistic regression or the SVM and select how many features you want left.

I think the choice of the best method depends on the data, so more information is necessary.

Comment: Can u tell how Tree based modeling algorithm like XGBoost do auto matically feature selection ??

Comment: Yes, usually tree based methods are able to do that. Check an example here: http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/